# Añadir atributo HTML (name, alt, etc.) a una etiqueta HTML en WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, plugin

Me han encargado corregir pequeños detalles de HTML en un proyecto hecho en WordPress.

Os pongo algunos ejemplos:

- Poner el atributo "alt" a las etiquetas  que no lo tengan
- Poner el atributo "title" a las etiquetas  que no lo tengan
- Etc.

El problema es que ese código HTML no lo he escrito yo, sino que lo ha generado el propio WordPress.

No tengo ni idea de cómo se modifica. Sabría hacerlo si yo hubiera desarrollado el proyecto desde cero, pero al ser en un CMS no sé cómo acceder a ese código y hacer lo que me piden...

Comment: Cuando usas un CMS como Wordpress, lo ideal es usar sus plugins para tratarlo, en caso de que no haya un plugin que haga lo que quieres (sería raro), entonces puedes hacer tu mismo un plugin con los ganchos apropiados a las funciones que desees de forma muy sencilla. Si la modificación es estructural, entonces puedes crear un theme hijo y modificar allí la estructura.

Answer (score 0):

Esta puede ser una solución agregarle un `js` al iniciar que genere el html deseado en este caso los attr `alt` y `title` puedes ser mas especifico agregándole una clase a cada elemento que deseas agregarle un `title` espero te ayude saludos

En el ejemplo el `html` de el `(button,input,img)` inicial izan como tal sin los atributos y se los agregamos con js en este caso jquery.

la function de jquery `.attr("atributo","valor a cambiar")` nos obtiene el `attr` en especifico para cambiarlo u obtenerlo, en este caso lo cambiamos.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button,input").attr("title","hola soy el nuevo title");
  $("img").attr('alt', 'Este alt es nuevo');
});
```

```css
  img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(225, 163, 247);
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" name="button">boton sin title</button>
  <input type="text" name="" value="input sin title">
  <img src="" alt="" >
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo con este plugins:

`Auto image alt text`

solo lo instalas y le das donde dice `add title` y esto colocara automaticamente el titulo a todas las imagenes atravez de su attributo `alt=""`

[weboficial](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-image-alt-text-with-yoast/)